# Show/Hide Series of Divs After X Seconds Without Loop

Tags: javascript

On page load, I'm trying to show a div1 for 10 seconds and then hide it, show `div2` for 3 seconds and then hide it, then show the last div3 without hiding it.

So I have in my css...

```
#show1, #show2, #show3 {display: none; }
```

In the html...

```
<div id="showhide">
<div id="show1">
<h2>Step 1: Checking if your area is eligible...</h2>
</div>
<div id="show2">
<h2>Success!</h2>
</div>
<div id="show3">
<h2>Just need to gather a little more information...</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

And a functioning show/hide script, but I'm not sure how to 1) make it not loop and 2) set different intervals for show/hide of div1 and div2.

```
$(function () {

var counter = 0,
divs = $('#show1, #show2, #show3');

function showDiv () {
divs.hide() // hide all divs
.filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
.show('fast'); // and show it

counter++;
}; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

showDiv(); // show first div    

setInterval(function () {
showDiv(); // show next div
}, 1 * 1000); // do this every 10 seconds    

});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `data-nextid="show2" data-showtimeout="10" class="hide-div" style="display:none;"`to `<div>` tags.

`data-nextid` will have id of next div to show.

`data-showtimeout`will have value of display time for current div.

`hide-div` class is use for set all such div to hide at function call.

`style="display:none;"` to each div will hide all div initially.

Removed CSS `#show1, #show2, #show3 {display: none; }`

Added initial call for display first div `displayDivWithTimer.apply($('#show1'));` inside `$(document).ready()`.

```js
function displayDivWithTimer() { 
  $(this).css('display', 'block');
  var timeout = $(this).attr('data-showtimeout');
  var nextid = $(this).attr('data-nextid');
  //console.log("timeout:" + timeout + ", nextid:" + nextid);
  if (timeout && nextid) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.hide-div').css('display', 'none');
      displayDivWithTimer.apply($('#' + nextid));
    }, parseInt(timeout) * 1000);
  }  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    displayDivWithTimer.apply($('#show1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="showhide">
  <div data-nextid="show2" data-showtimeout="10" id="show1" class="hide-div" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Step 1: Checking if your area is eligible...</h2>
  </div>
  <div data-nextid="show3" data-showtimeout="3" id="show2" class="hide-div" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Success!</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="show3" class="hide-div" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Just need to gather a little more information...</h2>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly as you have and for some reason it won't show any divs.

Comment: Added brief instruction of what I have done. Minor change to code has done. If your code still not working then uncomment console.log line and observe. I hope this will help you.

Comment: it works! Thank you very much... this is a big help.